# Pi4B controlling servos with a (az-delivery) PCA9685 board, servo not moving

Tags: pi-4, servo

I started with hooking up the PCA9685 board to my Pi4B and then installing the adafruit PCA9685 library.

I followed this guide
https://medium.com/@poojakose5/control-servos-using-16-channel-servo-driver-and-raspberry-pi-8b9318ce7762
except that I installed the latest adafruit library

I tried different examples I found but the servos don't move.

I get no errors but there's no movement.

When going through a loop

```
for i in range(180):
    servo.angle = i
    print(servo.angle)
```

it prints the angle from 0 to 180, but....no moving servos.

What could be wrong?
It's the az-delivery PCA9685 board (https://www.az-delivery.com/products/pca9685-servotreiber), could there be a problem with that.

I'm using the AZDelivery SG90 Micro Servo Motor 9G

Also when I execute `sudo i2cdetect -y 1`
I get

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f
00: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: 40 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: 70 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

That's ok I guess.

Below are the images showing the connections.

[image: pi4B]
[image: PCA9685]

Comment: We need more information.  There are plenty of similar questions.  Look at them then edit yours with the needed info.

Comment: I made some edits to make my problems more clear

Comment: Are you using a second power supply for the servos? Also, it would be very useful if you included photos of your equipment.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a 5V supply for the servo motors on the PCA9685 board

Answer (score 1):

The device appears to be wired correctly.

Try running this example code.

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_PCA9685_py

Unzip then

```
sudo pigpiod
python PCA9685.py
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried it, when I ran python PCA9685.py I got an importerr: ,no module pigpio
so I used python3 PCA9685.py, that ran without error, but also without movement.
I took some time before the cursor came back so I guess it's doing something.

Comment: Sounds like duff servos or power supply.  Try connecting a servo directly to the Pi (5V, ground, plus GPIO).  If you connect to GPIO4 (pin 7) give the command `pigs s 4 1000` then `pigs s 4 2000`.  It should move if the servo is ok.

Comment: when I connect the servo directly to the Pi I can get them to move with those commands, so the servo's are ok.

Comment: I suggest you connect one of the PCA9685 PWM outputs to a Pi GPIO set in read mode.  Then use [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) or [monitor.py](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py) to check that a signal is being generated when you run a test.    Perhaps the power supply is wrongly connected.

Comment: Omg, that was it, the power supply cables where wrongly connected. Now they're moving  like they should. Thanks for thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is you connected 3.3 V [Pi] -> 3.3 V/5 V PCA9685.

You can use 5 V from the Pi or connect an external power source to the V+ pin.